# How to include a carriage return in an argument to an executable?

Tags: ascii, command-line-arguments, executable, carriage-return

I have a simple program that prints out `argv` character by character, and I want to pass in carriage return (`'\r'`  or ASCII# 0x0D) as a program argument. How do I achieve this in linux OS (Ubuntu)? I am using bash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;  

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {     
        char* curr = argv[i];
        while(*curr != '\0') {
            printf("[%c %x] ", *curr, *curr);
            curr++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming our executable program is called `test`, if the input is :

```
./test hi
```

Then we get

```
[h 68] [i 69]
```

Or if I want to print out newline character, I execute program with command :

```
./test '[Enter Pressed]'
```

Then we get

```
[
 0a]
```

What should I type for program argument so that it prints out the carriage return? Or more generally any ASCII character that are not supported by keyboard?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This actually isn't a C question; the question is, how to include a carriage return in an argument to an executable.

You haven't indicated what shell you're using, but in many shells, you can write this:

```
./test $'\r'
```

where `$'...'` is a special quoting notation that allows you to use C-style escape sequences. (See, for example, [§3.1.2.4 "ANSI-C Quoting" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).)

If your shell does not support that notation, but is POSIX-compliant, you can make use of `printf` to process the escape sequences for you:

```
./test "$(printf '\r')"
```

(See [§2.6.3 "Command Substitution" in the *Shell Command Language* portion of the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03), plus [the documentation for the `printf` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html).)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks. I better read your links for more depths.

Comment: Based on the this answer, you can use $'\r\n' to separate multiple items in a list which needs to be sent as param list with CRLF between items