# Sending email using default email client in c#

Tags: c#, email

This code works EXCEPT the body portion (string cntrmsg) does not acknowlege the carriage returns within the string.

I get all one line (phone number x'd out for privacy). This is what I'm getting:

Inspection Type: FINAL BUILDING INSPECTIONInspection Results: APPROVEDMet with Jeremy xxx xxx xxxx, at the finish line for everything, mostly complete minus a few door locks and setting a sink or two. Craig will follow through with a plumbing final yet. No issues observed on our end.

Any way around that?

```
private void sendemail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // see who applied for permit then see who email should be sent to if email is missing
        string mailto = "";
        string ownremail = "";
        SqlCommand comm = GetConnectedClass.newsqlconnection("SELECT ApplCode,OwnrEmail from dbo.prmtmain WHERE PrmtTNum = @inspptno");
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inspptno", inspptno.Text);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());

        if (dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("ApplCode") == "O")
        {   if (dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("OwnrEmail") != "")
            { mailto = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("OwnrEmail"); ownremail = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("OwnrEmail"); }
            else { mailto = "Please enter an email address..."; }
        }
        if (dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("ApplCode") == "C")
        {
            // go get cntremail / if no cntr email see if owner has one else generic msg to enter addr
            comm = GetConnectedClass.newsqlconnection("SELECT CntrEmail FROM dbo.cntrmast WHERE CntrName = @cntrname");
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cntrname", cntrname.Text);
            dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
            if (dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("CntrEmail") != "")
            { mailto = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("CntrEmail"); }
            else if (ownremail != "")
            { mailto = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("OwnrEmail"); }
            else { mailto = "Please enter an email address..."; }
        }
        if (dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("ApplCode") != "O" && dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("ApplCode") != "C")
        {  mailto = "Please enter an email address..."; }

        string rslt = "";
        if (result.Text.Trim() == "A")
        { rslt = "APPROVED"; }
        else if (result.Text.Trim() == "C")
        { rslt = "CONDITIONALLY APPROVED"; }
        else if (result.Text == "V")
        { rslt = "VIOLATON"; }
        else if (result.Text == "NONE")
        { rslt = "No Results Posted"; }

        // construct body    
        string cntrmsg = @"Inspection Type: " + inspdesc.Text + "\r\nInspection Results: " + rslt +
                         "\r\n"+remarks.Text;
        if (app.serinumb == "795")
        { cntrmsg = cntrmsg + "\r\nAll corrections must be fixed within 30 days. \r\nOccupancy may not take place until a Final Occupancy Certificate is Issued.  \nSubject to fines."; }
        if (app.serinumb == "849")//piperton GO GET REINSPFEE ASK????
        { cntrmsg = cntrmsg + "\r\nThis inspection has failed. A re-inspection fee of $"; }

        // construct address/subject
            string email = "mailto:" + mailto + "?subject=" + "Address: " + jobaddress.Text + 
                       " Permit #: " + inspptno.Text + " Insp #: " + Convert.ToString(inspnumb.Text) +
                       "&body="+ cntrmsg;

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = email;

        proc.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Are you going between different operating systems like windows to linux?  The returns are different and will not be translated.

Comment: By calling Process.Start, you are essentially calling running it from the command line. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922734/how-to-include-a-carriage-return-in-an-argument-to-an-executable

Comment: @jdweng No this is all Windows..

Comment: Check with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see what characters are being returned.  You may be getting a unicode return.  The encoding method should be in the header of the response.